# Values change after 'scanf'

Tags: c

I am looking to implement a stack in c. While trying to implement this, I came across a problem that neither me nor my teacher know what to do with. I initialize some values in a struct (Stack) and after the scanf function is called, the values of the elements in that stack seem to have changed for some reason.

I reduced the code to the bare minimum and the problem still occurs. Also, it seems to be a problem on my computer, but when I try the program on a different computer it magically works. I try not to say 'my computer does it wrongly', but it is quite frustrating.

**Code example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct Stack {
    int elementSize;
} Stack;

int stackInit(Stack *stack, int elementSize);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Stack stack;
    stackInit(&stack,sizeof(char));
    char menuInput;

    printf("[main] stack->elementSize = %d\n",stack.elementSize); //OK
    scanf("\n%s", &menuInput); //USER INPUT
    printf("[main] stack->elementSize = %d\n",stack.elementSize); //NOK
}

int stackInit(Stack *stack, int elementSize){
    stack->elementSize = elementSize;
    printf("[stackInit] stack->elementSize = %d\n",stack->elementSize); //OK
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
[stackInit] stack->elementSize = 1
[main] stack->elementSize = 1
1
[main] stack->elementSize = 0
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which architecture you are running your program on? I have never seen integer with size as 1 byte...its either 2 or 4 bytes...

Comment: Oh no (sorry answering so late)
It seems like I actually made a typo in the question there, my bad/
I edited it now,

Nice catch, btw!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to read a string (%s -> char*) into a char that works but will overwrite the data next to the char. Here:

```
char menuInput;
[...]
scanf("\n%s", &menuInput); //USER INPUT
```

Should be:

```
char menuInput;
[...]
scanf("\n%c", &menuInput); //USER INPUT
```